# How to validate input type in loop condition

Tags: javascript, php

I have foreach loop input type and I want to validate it with JavaScript.

```
<tbody>
  <?php $no=1; $total=0; $total1=0;$total2=0;$total3=0; foreach ($modal as $id=>$r){ ?>

  <tr class="gradeU">
    <td> 
      <input type="hidden" name="modal[<?php echo $r->t_detail_id ?>][id_nego]" class="form-control"    value="<?php echo $r->t_detail_id ?>">
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $r->jenis_barang ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $r->qty ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $r->mata_uang ?> <?php echo number_format($r->harga) ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $r->mata_uang ?> <?php echo number_format($r->ppn) ?>
     <td><input type="text" name="modal[<?php echo $r->t_detail_id ?>][penawaran]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r->harga_penawaran ?> ">
     </td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="modal[<?php echo $r->t_detail_id ?>][nego]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r->harga_nego ?>"id="x"></td>
     <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r->harga ?>"></td>
     <td colspan="5"><button type="submit" name="submit1" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="myFunction()">Verify</button></td>
```

In `myFunction`, I tried like this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var y= document.getElementById("y").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("x").value;

  if (x > y) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<font color=red>Price Nego < HPS Price"; 
  } else if(x <= y) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<font color=green>PRice Nego OK";
    document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

Only the last loop input type is validated.
I have tried making many changes to it, but to no result.

Comment: every ID MUST be unique - that is why the document.getElementById calls only select last element

Comment: so how to make it call all element ? i need all value loop in this <input type="text" name="modal[<?php echo $r->t_detail_id ?>][nego]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $r->harga_nego ?>"id="x"> to validate

Comment: If there are multiple rows ( as the loop would suggest ) how would your function decide which values to use for the final task of populating `demo` and enabling a submit button? The button is a `submit` button so it will submit the form and anything  done by the function would be redundant. Should that be a regular button instead? Where are the elements referenced in that function (`id=demo` and `id=submit`)?

Comment: Is the function supposed to process ALL input elements or only those elements that appear in the same table row?

Comment: its only those elements in the same table

Answer (score 0):

i tried myFunction like this and its worked.
thanks guys

```js
 function myFunction() {
var allinputs=  document.querySelectorAll(".form-control1");
 var  a= document.querySelectorAll('input[type="hidden"][name="y"]');
var myLength = allinputs.length;
 
  for (var i = 0;i < myLength ; ++i) {
    if (allinputs[i].value > a[i].value) {
    allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<font color=red>Harga Negosiasi Harus Dibawah Harga HPS"; 

   
    }else if(allinputs[i].value < a[i].value) {
  
      allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "lime";  
      document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute("disabled");
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<font color=green>Harga Negosiasi OK"; 

    }else if(allinputs[i].value == a[i].value) {
  
      allinputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute("disabled");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="<font color=green>Harga Negosiasi OK";

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    }
  }
```